# How to implement google's voice recognition in mvc that compatible for all browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, webkitspeechrecognition

I am trying to implement voice recognition functionality in my mvc application. I used `webkitSpeechRecognition` to achieve this but it is working on chrome only.

So first of all, Is it possible to get it for all browser (in mvc)?
what should I do to make it working on all browsers? 
Is there any another approach or I need to amend something else in it only?

Please suggest some references or correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

the webkitSpeechRecognition api has bad support for all web browsers, look the  following table:

[image]

to use it in firefox look the official documentation in MND: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I already gone through this and tried to identify different speech recognition api. but my code returns error on var myRecognition = new SpeechRecognition(); ("undefined")

Comment: @HiteshGupta, first, check if the SpeechRecognitionApi is supported, you can use modernizr to do this: https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses

Comment: Yes according to modernizr, it's supported by my firefox 44.0b1 but still getting error "ReferenceError: SpeechRecognition is not defined"